# Advanced gather in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensor:

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
b = torch.rand(3, 5)
```

I want to index `b` according to `a` by the following rule:

```
c1 = b[range(a.shape[1]), a[0]]
c2 = b[range(a.shape[1]), a[1]]
c = torch.cat([c1, c2], dim=0)
```

How can I achieve that in one line (a batched solution)?

Comment: I tried this: `r = torch.arange(3).expand(a.shape).reshape(-1)`, `a_ = a.view(-1)`, `c = b[r, a_]`.

But is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: `torch.masked_select` - [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html#torch.masked_select) - could be useful so the problem becomes how to get the mask from your `a` tensor.